# Chef deploy_revision not creating git revision folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, chef-infra

I am trying deploy rails app using chef on vagrant machine. I am using depoly_revision resource to deploy rails application. But I am getting following error.

> FATAL: Errno::ENOENT: deploy_revision[/var/www/app_name] (applications::recipe_name line 130) had an error: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /var/www/app_name/releases/03d4548d9351df442ec9b5e08baef5b4ec3fce1b

My deploy block is as follows

```rb
directory "/var/www" do
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    action :create
  end

  directory "/var/www/#{app_name}" do
    owner app_name
    group app_name
  end

  directory "/var/www/#{app_name}/shared/" do
    owner app_name
    group app_name
  end

  directory "/var/www/#{app_name}/releases/" do
    owner app_name
    group app_name
  end

  directory "/var/www/#{app_name}/shared/cached-copy" do
    owner app_name
    group app_name
  end

deploy_revision deploy_to do
  deploy_to "/var/www/#{app_name}"
  action app_environment_config["action"]
  repo app_config["repository"]
  revision app_environment_config["revision"]
  user app_name
  group app_name
  migrate params[:migrate]
  migration_command "rake db:migrate --trace &> migrate.log"
  environment("RAILS_ENV" => env, "APPLICATION_NAME" => app_name)
  shallow_clone true
  symlinks("assets" => "public/assets", "pids" => "tmp/pids", "sockets" => "tmp/sockets", "log" => "log")
  symlink_before_migrate({})

  before_migrate do
    execute "bundle install --path #{deploy_to}/shared/bundle --deployment --without development test" do
      cwd release_path
      user app_name
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `/var/www/#{app_name}` isn't existing, is it?

Answer (score 0):

you probably just need to create the directory first:

```
directory "/var/www/#{app_name}" do
  user app_name
  group app_name
end
```